# How to get stage-specific important fields from pipedrive API

Tags: pipedrive-api

In pipedrive you can tag fields as **important** for some pipeline stages.

For all the stages in my pipelines I would like to get the list of those important fields via an API request.

The closest I found on the API documentation was the `GET /organizationFields` [request](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#!/OrganizationFields/get_organizationFields) which gives a boolean `important_flag` for each field. But it does not depend on the stage, so that is not what I'm looking for.

Is it actually possible to do that ?

Comment: According to Pipedrive support this is not possible.